# Get inherited groupId with readMavenPom

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pom.xml

I have a question concerning `readMavenPom` ([Link to doc](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readmavenpom-read-a-maven-project-file)) utility from Jenkins pipelines.

I have a project with a `pom.xml` where no `groupId` is defined but this `pom.xml` has a parent pom with a a defined `groupId`. (It could happen that, even this parent doesn't have a defined `groupId` and is the parent.parent the one that has it).

Is there a way to get the, let's say, *effective* `groupId` in an elegant way?

I'm currently getting `null` with the getGroupId() method (or property accessor `.groupId`)

NOTE: With elegant way I mean, not looping into parents and checking if groupId is not null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, what do you need the groupId for?

Comment: probably he needs to do something doogey with it.....

Comment: Anyway that'a bug to open cause readMavenProject should evaluate the actual project and not the xml content....

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the [maven-help-plugin:evaluate](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html) goal via command line which can give you what you need.

The following will exactly extract the groupId of the project and will handle all the things based on your inheritance part.

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.groupId -q -DforceStdout
```

This could be done in a separate stage step of the Jenkins Pipeline.